# Max Characters in Vertical Scroll

Tags: css

I looked and couldn't find an answer to this:

I created , in CSS, a vertical scroll, using a div tag.  I am using a PC, and when the browser is maximized, the entire message scrolls, which is currently two lines.  When I reduce the browser window (not minimize), the 2nd half of the message gets cut off.

http://clipnclear.com/cnc/dev/scrollup.htm

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `height: 100%`.

You translate the y by 100% of the p element, but its container is smaller than itself so it translates on the y only by 50px and not by the p element height.

Comment: by commenting out or removing the height: 100%; is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: No, remove just this one will scroll the whole p element and not just half of it.